# Toolbar - Android 10

Tags: android, android-studio, operating-system, android-toolbar, menubar

I'm trying to change the background and title color of the toolbar on Android 10.

In the **xml** file, I have the following (in *style*):

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/C_Yellow</item>
<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/CustomStyle</item>
```

(in *resources*):

```
<style name="CustomStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/B_Blue</item>
</style>
```

It works on Android 4.4; however, on Android 10, it just has a black background with white text.

What should I do in order to change both background and title color on Android 10?

Comment: Are you using a toolbar in your layout? where is <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/CustomStyle</item> ?

Comment: I tried putting it in the **xml** file but it shows me two toolbars (the upper one is the default one which has black background and the lower one is the one I made with a background color I want).

Answer (score 0):

Just use android:foregroundTint for text color and icons if present, secondly for background use android:background and set color according to your choice